# Deployed Rails app doesn't route the different controllers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have finally deployed my rails app to my digital ocean server after many mistakes and stumbles to come across another fatal one. My app has a few different controllers pages, which serves my blog portion and my portfolio section and its with those that I have problems.

```
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:22.030934 #27271]  INFO -- : [f2cf3522-4f86-4a2f-bb8d-9799ae35afd9]   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5)
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:22.031181 #27271]  INFO -- : [f2cf3522-4f86-4a2f-bb8d-9799ae35afd9] Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 7.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 3044)
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.232959 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4] Started GET "/projects" for 45.56.196.34 at 2020-04-03 19:53:24 +0000
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.234018 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4] Processing by PortfoliosController#index as HTML
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.237033 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   Rendering portfolios/index.html.erb within layouts/portfolio
D, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.239188 #27271] DEBUG -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   ESC[1mESC[36mUser Load (0.4ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mESC[34mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1ESC[0m
D, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.240287 #27271] DEBUG -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   ESC[1mESC[36mProject Load (0.3ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mESC[34mSELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects`ESC[0m
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.241632 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   Rendered collection of templates [0 times] (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3)
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.241743 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   Rendered portfolios/index.html.erb within layouts/portfolio (Duration: 4.6ms | Allocations: 930)
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.244944 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4] [Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
I, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.245468 #27271]  INFO -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 3189)
F, [2020-04-03T19:53:24.246332 #27271] FATAL -- : [61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find portfolios in /home/deploy/jdhall/releases/20200403195139/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.css": "/packs/css/application-772b9a14.css",
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-a51f41026dd096a1e6d2.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-a51f41026dd096a1e6d2.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "css": [
        "/packs/css/application-772b9a14.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-a51f41026dd096a1e6d2.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-a51f41026dd096a1e6d2.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
):
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]      6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]      7: 
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]      8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'portfolios', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]      9:     <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'portfolios', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]     10:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]     11:   </head>
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]     12: 
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4]   
[61f9f7ba-5dc0-49d0-a388-09c8eae801b4] app/views/layouts/portfolio.html.erb:9
```

in the manifest is has this

```
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-136976a59d7b66c360f5.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-136976a59d7b66c360f5.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-136976a59d7b66c360f5.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-136976a59d7b66c360f5.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Because the blog and portfolio sections have different css I am assuming thats why the problem has happened but I don't know how to fix it. I have tried putting a blogs.scss and portfolios.scss in the pack folder. But it didnt work.

Comment: This will likely help: https://prathamesh.tech/2020/03/25/webpacker-5-0-released/

Comment: Thank you @RoyZwambag